# Taskdef class com.temp.install.common.action.UserInstallDirRule cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader

Tags: java, xml, jar, ant, taskdef

I have created a jar with the .class files and the dependency libraries which are required for executing the class files using the below jar code

```
<target name="jar" depends="clean">
    <jar destfile="${basedir}/lib/HelloWorld.jar">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${basedir}/lib" includes="*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="/com/temp/**" />
        <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="build.properties"/>
        <manifest>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="./HelloWorld.jar"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Now i have written other build.xml to run taskdef actions using this jar but the following error occurs when i try to invoke the class files using the taskdef actions even though the class files and their dependencies are present in the same jar.

> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\Users\kh2139\Desktop\New folder\build.xml:4: taskdef class com.temp.install.common.action.UserInstallDirRule cannot be found
>    using the classloader AntClassLoader[C:\Users\kh2139\Desktop\New folder\HelloWorld.jar]

Attaching my build.xml code below which is used to run taskdef actions on the HelloWorld.jar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <project name="MyTask" basedir="." default="use">
<target name="use" description="Use the Task" >
    <taskdef name="helloworld1" classname="com.temp.install.common.action.UserInstallDirRule" classpath="HelloWorld.jar"/>
    <helloworld1/>
    <taskdef name="helloworld" classname="com.temp.install.common.action.EncryptionGUID" classpath="HelloWorld.jar"/>
    <helloworld/>
</target>
</project>
```

PS: I could able to run the build.xml file successfully without errors when i specify the lib folder in the location where i place HelloWorld.jar and give the classpath to the lib folder in the taskdef actions.

But my issue is i want to use the same jar to contain the dependencies that are used while executing the classes.

Comment: @datv I've posted my previous comment as an answer. I've also deleted the original comment so it doesn't duplicate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that Java cannot find `UserInstallDirRule.class` in `HelloWorld.jar`. To determine if `HelloWorld.jar` contains the class, try running the `jar.exe` program included with the JDK.

Here's an example of running `jar.exe` in a Windows Command Prompt:

```
C:\>jar.exe tf "C:\Users\kh2139\Desktop\New folder\HelloWorld.jar"
```

The output will show whether `UserInstallDirRule.class` is in the JAR file.

Comment: +1 for translating **"Taskdef class... AntClassLoader"**  to *"The error indicates that Java cannot find UserInstallDirRule.class in HelloWorld.jar"*